# How can I configure my iOS device to use Internet via Bluetooth tethering as a metered connection?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, internet, tethering, ios

I use Internet on my iPhone 12 Mini via Bluetooth tethering. How can I configure my iOS device to use that Internet via Bluetooth tethering as a metered connection?

---

Answering comments:

> What are you connecting your 12 mini to?

Another iPhone.

> When you attempt to connect over Bluetooth, what happens?

The connection is successful. I get Internet via Bluetooth tethering.

Comment: We can’t advise you how to configure an *Android* device

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as written it’s not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help].

Comment: @Allan thanks, was typo, fixed

Comment: We need lots more details.  What are you connecting your 12 mini to?  When you attempt to connect over Bluetooth, what happens?

Comment: @Allan thanks, added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I [read](https://redd.it/1bj1cff), iOS devices can't be natively configured to use that Internet via Bluetooth tethering as a metered connection.